# Default select in Autocomplte component in Material UI react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, material-ui

I have autocomplete input from react material ui.

I am trying to set an default selected value when an user comes to edit this input.

I can select the option via getOptionSelected but that option's name is not showing up.

```
<Autocomplete
              value={form && form.productID}
              options={categories && categories}
              getOptionDisabled={(option) =>
                option.partnerId && !option.isApproved
              }
             
              getOptionSelected={(option, value) => value === option._id}
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
              renderOption={(option) => (
                <Grid container justify="space-between">
                  {option.name}
                </Grid>
              )}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField {...params} label="Products" variant="outlined" />
              )}
            />
```

how can i create an default selected value,
Note: I need the renderOption in Grid since i am using some chips, tooltips inside the renderOption

my endpoint is like this

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "_id": "5f659a5d1407c6729c71f833",
        "name": "Mutton",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f659a1a1407c6729c71f832",
        "name": "Chicken",
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f6599d41407c6729c71f831",
        "name": "Fish",
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give a default value, then you need to set defaultValue property.

```
<Autocomplete
              value={form && form.productID}
              options={categories && categories}
              getOptionDisabled={(option) =>
                option.partnerId && !option.isApproved
              }
             
              getOptionSelected={(option, value) => value === option._id}
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
              renderOption={(option) => (
                <Grid container justify="space-between">
                  {option.name}
                </Grid>
              )}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField {...params} label="Products" variant="outlined" />
              )}
              defaultValue={you default goes here}
            />
```

Comment: My issues is, my default value is a string (id of a category). i get an array of objects as my options. then how can i set a default value?

Comment: You need a filter function, which returns  your id based on filter.

Comment: i tried that, since my form and categories are async api, before i filter through categories tha Autocomplete gets rendered and not updating

Comment: [link to my gist of the code](https://gist.github.com/sudhakarbhra/63d2de215e39522bf42e91aba9132d8f)